# Only variables should be passed by reference - Laravel 5

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

When I did

```
return asort(array_count_values(Visitor::all()->pluck('device')->toArray()));
```

I kept getting

> Only variables should be passed by reference

This is an array

```
array_count_values(Visitor::all()->pluck('device')->toArray())
```

It returns

```
{
    iPhone: 202,
    Windows NT 6.1: 2428,
    Windows NT 10.0: 2588,
    Macintosh: 1397,
    iPad: 12,
    Windows NT 6.2: 50,
    Windows NT 6.3: 90,
    X11: 442,
    compatible: 1813,
    Windows NT 5.1: 97,
    Linux: 227,
    Windows: 86,
    TweetmemeBot/4.0: 8,
    ) { :: 14,
    Windows NT 6.0: 7,
    User-Agent,Mozilla/5.0 : 1,
    KHTML, like Gecko: 6,
    Unknown: 11,
    Android: 1,
    Android 7.1.1: 1,
    Android 7.1.2: 2,
    Windows NT x.y: 2,
    Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 : 7,
    Windows NT 5.0: 1,
    Windows NT 8.0: 1,
    web crawler :: robots.txt exclude elefent: 1,
    Windows NT: 1,
    Linux 4.4.0-116-generic: 1
}
```

I want to sort them desc base on array_count_values.

Why do I get that error ?

Comment: assign it first `$data = array_count_values(Visitor::all()->pluck('device')->toArray()); arsort($data); return $data;` its just few lines

Comment: I break it apart like that you did. same resule.

Comment: laravel 5.8 - see the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SORT_NATURAL` flag should be useful in your case. I am considering pluck is returning your data as I have to sort.

```
arsort($arr,SORT_NATURAL);
// I suggest you write this in separate line because it  
// Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure which I don't think you want.
// Please see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php
return $arr;
```

> **Note:-** SORT_NATURAL - compare items as strings using "natural ordering" like [natsort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [Windows NT 10.0] => 2588
    [Windows NT 6.1] => 2428
    [compatible] => 1813
    [Macintosh] => 1397
    [X11] => 442
    [Linux] => 227
    [iPhone] => 202
    [Windows NT 5.1] => 97
    [Windows NT 6.3] => 90
    [Windows] => 86
    [Windows NT 6.2] => 50
    [) { :] => 14
    [iPad] => 12
    [Unknown] => 11
    [TweetmemeBot/4.0] => 8
    [Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 ] => 7
    [Windows NT 6.0] => 7
    [KHTML, like Gecko] => 6
    [Android 7.1.2] => 2
    [Windows NT x.y] => 2
    [Android] => 1
    [Android 7.1.1] => 1
    [User-Agent,Mozilla/5.0 ] => 1
    [Windows NT 5.0] => 1
    [Windows NT 8.0] => 1
    [web crawler :: robots.txt exclude elefent] => 1
    [Windows NT] => 1
    [Linux 4.4.0-116-generic] => 1
)
```

[Demo.](https://3v4l.org/JaVpq)

**EDIT**

```
$data = Visitor::all()->pluck('device')->toArray();
$retArr = array_count_values($data);
arsort($retArr,SORT_NATURAL);
return $retArr;
```

Comment: can you show me the piece of code which is not working? It should match with my edit portion of answer.

Answer (score 1):

asort() expects an array parameter variable (not the result of a function like toArray()) . This function modifies the array itself (is not returning the sorted array), and returns `true` on success or `false` on error.

```
asort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] ) : bool
```

Just assign the result to a `$variable` and then use `asort($variable)` or any other array sorting function with `&$array` argument (passed by **reference**)

```
$result = array_count_values(Visitor::all()->pluck('device')->toArray());
return asort($result);
```

Comment: please look at my array content and update your answer accoridinly.